# Can I populate a column in telerik grid from code behind

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

Hi I am working on an asp.net page and I want to fill 1 column in my grid from code behind is that possible.
If I am using

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn AllowSorting="false" UniqueName="AdditionalMargin" DataField="AdditionalMargin"
                                        HeaderText="ADD Margin" HeaderTooltip="ADD Margin" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                                        Aggregate="Sum" DataFormatString="{0:0.00}" FooterAggregateFormatString="{0:0.00}">
                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

It is not possible I guess so please let me know if it is possible or not if possible please give some inputs.

Comment: how do you load the grid ?

Comment: I am getting data in dataset and bind it to the grid.All other column i can fill from dataset but 1 particular column I want to fill by my own as it needs some aggregate function and my sp will become very long If I tried to add that also

Comment: you can add a new column to the datatable and calculate the aggregate function and store the value in that column and bind that in grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code to add a column and set value to it.

```
DataTable dt = sql.ExecuteDataTable("sp_MyProc");

dt.Columns.Add("NewColumn", typeof(System.Int32)); //change the datatype to your need.

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    //need to set value to NewColumn column
    row["NewColumn"] = 0;   // or set it to some other value
}
```